# How to find out if a currently logged in user belongs to a specific security group in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to find out if a specific user belongs to a particular group for an asp website. In asp.net I know we have the option 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole'. I want to know if we have any alternative for this in classic asp. Is there any other way this can be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VB Script in your .ASP page, you could use something like this

```
<%
strDomain = "YOURDOMAIN"
strUserName = "USERACCOUNT"
strGroupName = "Domain Users"

Set ObjUser = Getobject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strUserName & ",user")
For Each objGroup in ObjUser.Groups
    If UCase(strGroupName) = UCase(objGroup.Name) Then 
        'Found a match!
    End If
Next
%>
```